# How to compile INET with 3rd party dll (libaudiofile)

Tags: omnet++

I need to compile INET with some audio feature. I am using Omnet++ 5.1 with INET 3.5.0. 
From audiofile 0.3.6 Package I added 2 needed files audiofile.h and aupvlist.h
Now when I build it there are missing functions `afWriteFrames'`afInitSampleFormat' etc. This functions should be defined in libaudiofile.dll
My problem is how to take the functions from the dll?

I added path to the library libaudiofile.dll but Omnet don't want to take the functions. I tried to copy the libaudiofile.dll to Windows\System32 and SysWOW64 but nothing worked. Still the same error.

```
make MODE=release all 
cd src && /usr/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory '/d/OmnetWorkspace/inet-dev/src'
*** COMPILING with:
g++ -c -std=c++11 -O2 -DNDEBUG=1 -MMD -MP -MF .d    -isystem /usr/include -isystem /mingw64/include -fno-stack-protector  -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DPREFER_QTENV -DWITH_QTENV -DWITH_TKENV -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER -              
*** LINKING with:
g++ -shared  -o ../out/gcc-release/src/libINET.dll -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--whole-archive  -lwsock32 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -loppenvir -loppsim -lstdc++  -lOpenThreads -losg -losgText -losgDB -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil -Wl,-rpath,D:/omnetpp-5.1/lib     
Building...

Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-release/src/libINET.dll
.tmplib5636(RTPAVProfilePayload10Receiver.o):RTPAVProfilePayload10Receiver.cc:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `afWriteFrames'
.tmplib5636(RTPAVProfileSampleBasedAudioReceiver.o):RTPAVProfileSampleBasedAudioReceiver.cc:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `afNewFileSetup'
.tmplib5636(RTPAVProfileSampleBasedAudioReceiver.o):RTPAVProfileSampleBasedAudioReceiver.cc:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `afInitByteOrder'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1156: ../out/gcc-release/src/libINET.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/OmnetWorkspace/inet-dev/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `src/makefrag` in a text editor and add at the end:

```
LIBS += -L/c/libraries/audiofile  -laudiofile
```

It is assumed that `libaudiofile.dll` is in `C:\libraries\audiofile`.